# EJB,Hibernate and spring transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, ejb

I've a question regarding the use of the transaction manager in a context with EJB, Spring and Hibernate.
In our project we have an EJB stateless marked with the annotation @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED).
No further transaction has been defined so far.

Now every EJB calls a service. The latter is only a delegates the redirect the call to the final DAO. In every DAO we use the HibernateTemplate: the problem is that the session is closed soon after every get/load methods inside the DAOs. Why?

If I replace the HibernateTemplate with the classic Hibernate Session (best approach) and I call getSession().getTransaction().isActive() I get always false, but the session is still active 'till the end of the service call (the delegates mentioned above). After this the session closed. 
Why do I have this different behaviours? 
Isn't Spring/hibernate able to see the EJB transaction attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Fabio